# VLookup to Future Sheets and Files

Tags: excel-formula

I have a file recording monthly sheets. I am trying to organize a VLOOKUP to sheets that do not yet exist.

Example code: `=VLOOKUP($A$60,'C:/Users/JimW/Desktop//[MonthlySheets.xlsx]January18'!$A$2:$B$50,2,0)`

However, the code generates an error. Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your function in IFERROR() :

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$60,'C:/Users/JimW/Desktop//[MonthlySheets.xlsx]January18'!$A$2:$B$50,2,0),0)
```

The last ",0" is what you want displayed if the vlookup fails - often I put text such as "file closed" - the text needs to be in quotes.